# Black underlay behind Round Rect Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-animation

For some reason I have a black underlay under my round rect buttons. This only happens with the round rect buttons that are over a custom UIView. I have the Custom UIView to make borders  based on my clients design specs. If I remove the custom UIView (imgView3), then the buttons work fine. Also, after a brief period of time the black underlay disappears. Here is my code, I add in the buttons programmatically just to stay consistent but it also happens when I add the buttons via storyboard as well.

```
UIImageView *imgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(409, 129, 361, 217)];
// Get the Layer of any view
l = [imgView3 layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];

// You can even add a border
[l setBorderWidth:1];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
l.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
l.shadowRadius = 5.0;
l.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
l.shadowOpacity = 0.8;    
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:@"North" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(545, 161, 90, 53);
[imgView3 addSubview:button];

[self.view addSubview: imgView3]
```

Heres an image of what I'm speaking of:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Background Color of your button to Clear Color in the button's Attributes Inspector?

```
// or in code
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Is this a question, a comment or an answer?

Comment: All of them and pretty good point. The button's background might be set to Black color in the IB.

Comment: @Till, this is more of a suggestion. I am no pro in Xcode, but setting the background color to clear color solved some issues similar to this.

Comment: This ended up being the more correct answer now than what I had before

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to set its background color to clear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thank you all for your suggestions. Both replies were correct that I needed to use button.backgroundColor. However, the clearColor didn't work, I instead set it to whiteColor, which is the same color as the UIView behind it. That worked perfectly. Thank you all for your help again!

If anyone is having this same issue, this is the code that corrected it.
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];